# Pattern matching on a temporary tuple with mutable references

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and wondering if there is a natural way to write the following while still pattern matching on the tuple.

I have a tree like structure with `key`, `value`, `left` and `right` members. I want to create an insert function that looks something similar to

```
fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V> {
    match (k.cmp(self.k.borrow()), &mut self.left, &mut self.right) {
        (Ordering::Less, &mut None, _) => { self.left = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(k, v))); None },
        (Ordering::Less, &mut Some(ref mut left), _) => left.insert(k, v),
        (Ordering::Greater, &mut None, _) => { self.right = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(k, v))); None },
        (Ordering::Greater, &mut Some(ref mut right), _) => right.insert(k, v),
        (Ordering::Equal, _, _) => { let mut temp = v; std::mem::swap(self.v.borrow_mut(), temp.borrow_mut()); Some(temp) },
    }
}
```

I like how this clearly covers all the cases and the resulting actions, however this doesn't compile because `self.left` and `self.right` are mutably borrowed by the temporary tuple used in the match statement meaning that I can't modify `self.left` or `self.right` within the action arms of the match. The following alternative works

```
fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V> {
    match k.cmp(self.k.borrow()) {
        Ordering::Less => match self.left {
            None => { self.left = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(k, v))); None },
            Some(ref mut left) => left.insert(k, v),
        },
        Ordering::Greater => match self.right {
            None => { self.right = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(k, v))); None },
            Some(ref mut right) => right.insert(k, v),
        },
        Ordering::Equal => { let mut temp = v; std::mem::swap(self.v.borrow_mut(), temp.borrow_mut()); Some(temp) }
    }
}
```

and should be logically equivalent, but I feel like the former more clearly and concisely describes the problem. Being new to Rust I wasn't sure if there was some ability to extract the mutable reference from the tuple and change it from a `None` to `Some` value in the action, so figured I would ask if there are any alternatives I'm overlooking.

I've uploaded short snippets of the [working](http://is.gd/DdJY70) and [non-working](http://is.gd/iDnQfx) variations to the playpen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to get the mutable reference, as one can use an `@`-pattern (known as an as-pattern in Haskell) to bind an identifier to the value a whole pattern represents:

```
fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V> {
    match (k.cmp(self.k.borrow()), &mut self.left, &mut self.right) {
        (Ordering::Less, left @ &mut None, _) => {
            *left = Some(Box::new(TreeNode::new(k, v)));
            None
        }
    // ...
```

This is exactly like writing `let left = &mut self.left;` inside the match arm, but it has the useful advantage of working.

Comment: I had no idea such patterns were possible, this is good to know!

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity where would I find this behavior documented? I tried to find authoritative docs about what's possible in pattern matching, but couldn't really find much other than very trivial examples.

Comment: @ggriffiniii Looks like it's documented in the [Rust Reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html), in the [Match expressions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions) section: "Subpatterns can also be bound to variables by the use of the syntax `variable @ subpattern`."

Comment: @ggriffiniii It's mentioned (once) in [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#match-expressions), and also [in the Patterns section of the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#bindings) (although that's not as precise as it could be, [#25008](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25008)).